# F# code organization: types & modules

Tags: f#, module, code-organization, static-members

How do you decide between writing a function inside a module or as a static member of some type?

For example, in the source code of F#, there are lots of types that are defined along with a equally named module, as follows:

```
type MyType = // ...

[<CompilationRepresentation(CompilationRepresentationFlags.ModuleSuffix)>]
module MyType = // ...
```

Why don't you simply define the operations as static members of type MyType?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here are some notes about the technical distinctions.

**Modules can be 'open'ed** (unless they have RequireQualifiedAccessAttribute).  That is, if you put functions (`F` and `G`) in a module (`M`), then you can write

```
open M
... F x ... G x ...
```

whereas with a static method, you'd always write

```
... M.F x ... M.G x ...
```

**Module functions cannot be overloaded**.  Functions in a module are let-bound, and let-bound functions do not permit overloading.  If you want to be able to call both

```
X.F(someInt)
X.F(someInt, someString)
```

you must use `member`s of a type, which only work with 'qualified' calls (e.g. `type.StaticMember(...)` or `object.InstanceMember(...)`).

(Are there other differences?  I can't recall.)

Those are the main technical differences that influence the choice of one over the other.

Additionally, there is some tendency in the F# runtime (FSharp.Core.dll) to use modules only for F#-specific types (that are typically not used when doing interop with other .Net languages) and static methods for APIs that are more language-neutral.  For example, all the functions with curried parameters appear in modules (curried functions are non-trivial to call from other languages).

Comment: _"(Are there other differences? I can't recall.)"_, let me try: (1) F# naming guidelines want a static class member to start with a capital, a module let-binding with a lowercase letter; (2) types can be extended (use `with` syntax), modules cannot (unfortunately so); (3) type's static members are typically initialized when the type is first accessed, module let-binding are initialized much sooner, often if a related type in the same assembly is accessed (this is primarily important for members or bindings that are not functions).

Comment: And a similarity: (4) static members cannot be overloaded either when using F# function-style syntax (`static member x a b` cannot be overloaded, `static member x(a, b)` can). This has the advantage that static members can also be curried, but the disadvantage that they become harder to be called from C# etc.

Answer (score 4):

In F# I prefer a static member on a type over a function in a module if ...

1. I have to define the type irrespective of the member
2. The member is functionally related to the type I'm defining

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the other answers there is one more case to use Modules:

For value types they can help to define static properties that do not get re-evaluated every time they are accessed. for example:

```
type [<Struct>] Point =
    val x:float
    val y:float
    new (x,y) = {x=x;y=y}

    static member specialPoint1 = // sqrt is computed every time the property is accessed
        Point (sqrt 0.5 , sqrt 0.5 )

[<CompilationRepresentation(CompilationRepresentationFlags.ModuleSuffix)>]
module Point = 

    let specialPoint2 = // sqrt is computed only once when the Module is opened
        Point (sqrt 0.5 , sqrt 0.5 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Some big distinctions that weren't originally mentioned:

- Functions are first class values in F#, but static members are not. So you can write `objs |> Seq.map Obj.func` but you can't write `objs |> Seq.map Obj.Member`.
- Functions can be curried, but members cannot.
- The compiler will infer types automatically when you call a function, but not when you invoke a member. So you can write `let func obj = obj |> Obj.otherFunc` but you can't write `let func obj = obj.Member`.

Since members are more restricted, I usually use functions unless I explicitly want to support OOP/C#.

Comment: "Functions can be curried, but members cannot." -- Not sure what you mean, here.  For type MyType, I can write `static member goober a b c`, then invoke it with `|> MyType.goober a b`.

Comment: @MiloDC - You are correct. I wasn't aware of that when I wrote this answer. However, I wouldn't usually recommend creating curryable members, because it makes C# interop difficult.