# AutoOpen attribute in F#

Tags: f#, code-organization

What is the recommended doctrine for using the AutoOpen attribute ?

(This question is probably is in continuation to [when to use module function VS static function on similarly named type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214162/f-code-organization-types-modules) )

Expert F# states that "This can be useful when you’re defining ad hoc top-level operators
and functions:"

So this seems to be here to kind of diminish the module role in the code organization, when you technically need one to write the code but you remove its existence from a client perspective.

Is there something else ?
When do you use it ?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I think the main use for the `AutoOpen` attribute is when you want to make some let-bound values available when the user of your library opens a namespace. This is where the attribute is very useful, because I think libraries should generally export all definitions in *namespaces*, but for some purposes you need to export *values* and values cannot be defined inside a namespace.

Here is an example from [F# async extensions](https://github.com/tpetricek/FSharp.AsyncExtensions) which defines a computation builder and thus it needs to export `asyncSeq` value (but at the same time, all functionality is wrapped in a namespace):

```
namespace FSharp.Async

type AsyncSeq<'T> = (* ... *)
type AsyncSeqBuilder() = (* ... *)

[<AutoOpen>]
module GlobalValues = 
  let asyncSeq = AsyncSeqBuilder()
```

The user of the library can just write `open FSharp.Async` and they will see `asyncSeq`. I think the same pattern is used with various math libraries (where you also want to export simple-named functions.)

For modules (e.g. `List` and `Seq`), I think most of the people do not use `open` and access the functions via a module name (such as `List.map`), so although you can use this for nested modules, I have not seen that as frequently.

Answer (score 26):

It can be used to organize a module into sub-modules but present a unified/single-module view externally:

```
module Outer =

  [<AutoOpen>]
  module Inner1 =
    let f1() = ()

  [<AutoOpen>]
  module Inner2 =
    let f2() = ()

open Outer

let x = f1()
let y = f2()
```

[FParsec](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/reference/) does this: `open FParsec` opens all sub-modules (`Primitives`, `CharParsers`, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

*A little late to the party, but I wanted to add another usage.*

I tend to use `[<AutoOpen>]` to expose types within a namespace.

```ml
// SlimSql\Types.fs
namespace SlimSql

[<AutoOpen>]
module Types =

    type SqlOperation =
        {
            Statement : string
            Parameters : SqlParam list
        }
```

Then I can attach functions to the same type name without getting a compiler error that the name is already in use.

```ml
// SlimSql\SqlOperation.fs
namespace SlimSql

module SqlOperation =

    let merge (operations : SqlOperation list) : SqlOperation =
        ...

    let wrapInTransaction operation =
        ...
```

Then everything is nicely packaged up with the same name in consuming code. So when the user is looking for a behavior on SqlOperation data, they can naturally find it by typing `SqlOperation.` and Intellisense will show it. Much in the same way that types such as `List` are used in practice.

```ml
open SlimSql

let operations =
    [
        sql "INSERT INTO ...." [ p "@Value" 123; ... ]
        ...
    ]
let writeOp =
    operations
    |> SqlOperation.merge
    |> SqlOperation.wrapInTransaction
```

The SlimSql.Types module can also be opened by itself to access only the types for composition with other types.

I much prefer this solution to augmenting types with static members.