# Duplicate definition of type or module when defining a type and a module with the same name

Tags: f#

So as far as I understand, the convention is to define your type, and then define a module with the same name after it with the functions that operate on the type.

I'm trying to do that so I have this code

```
namespace Rand

type ImmutableRandom

module ImmutableRandom =
    open System

    val fromSeed : int -> ImmutableRandom
    val int : ImmutableRandom -> int
    val intInRange : ImmutableRandom -> int -> int -> int
    val double : ImmutableRandom -> double
    val next : ImmutableRandom -> ImmutableRandom
```

I'm getting the error that ImmutableRandom (the name of the module is underlined) is redefining a type or a module.

In the very same project, the identical setup works for a different type, with the only difference being that that type has a generic parameter, while ImmutableRandom doesn't.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Related post - [Shadowing and Nested function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2478079/465053)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `CompilationRepresentation` attribute on your module so that it has the same name in source, but not in IL:

```
namespace Rand

type ImmutableRandom

[<CompilationRepresentation(CompilationRepresentationFlags.ModuleSuffix)>]
module ImmutableRandom =
    open System

    val fromSeed : int -> ImmutableRandom
    val int : ImmutableRandom -> int
    val intInRange : ImmutableRandom -> int -> int -> int
    val double : ImmutableRandom -> double
    val next : ImmutableRandom -> ImmutableRandom
```

This will cause the module to be named `ImmutableRandomModule` in IL (and consequently from languages other than F#). This has a few advantages over static members, which are well summarized in this answer: [F# code organization: types & modules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2214347/636019)

Answer (score 1):

This works if the type is generic. Otherwise, there is ambiguity that the compiler cannot resolve on its own.

If you really feel the need to do this with a non-generic type, define all the functions as static members on the type. A bit less elegant, but you get the same surface API.